# Poetry git dependencies on AWS CodeCommit not working with SSO

Tags: python-poetry, aws-codecommit, aws-sso

I'm using poetry as my dependency manager for my python project, I've integrated external dependencies stored in a Git repository hosted on AWS CodeCommit. Since we changed our user management in AWS to SSO I can't use the git dependencies in poetry anymore.

To specify these dependencies in my 'pyproject.toml' file I used the given format explained in the [documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/).

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pandas = "^2.0.3"
mylib = {git = "https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/mylib.git"}
```

This approach worked fine.

However, we changed our user management in AWS to SSO (Identity Center) and I needed to use the git extension ['git-remote-codecommit'](https://pypi.org/project/git-remote-codecommit/) to communicate with my git repos in AWS CodeCommit.
But now I’m unable to integrate these external dependencies within Poetry. The heart of the issue lies in the necessity to modify the method by which I invoke and interact with the git repository.

I tried the following:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
pandas = "^2.0.3"
mylib = {git = "codecommit://my_profile@mylib.git"}
```

I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: This question will be somewhat naive: why cannot you publish the package and pip install it? It would easy for you.

Comment: I have found a solution for the problem. I have enabled the experimental Git feature of Poetry. With the command 'poetry config experimental.system-git-client  true ', you can integrate CodeCommit Git repositories with SSO in Poety.

Comment: I did not know this poetry feature. Thanks for enlightening us.